# Change first value by group in one column based on temporal data in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, temporal

I have a data frame in R with temporal data on different bears ('ID'), the month they are tracked ('Month'), and their departure onto the sea ice ('Departure'). Here is a simplified version with two ID's:

```
ID<-rep(c("A","B"),each=4)
Month<-c(4,4,5,5,11,11,11,12)
Departure<-c(rep(NA,times=4),"Departure",rep(NA,times=3))
data<-data.frame(ID,Month,Departure)
data

 ID Month Departure
1  A     4      <NA>
2  A     4      <NA>
3  A     5      <NA>
4  A     5      <NA>
5  B    11 Departure
6  B    11      <NA>
7  B    11      <NA>
8  B    12      <NA>
```

For ID's where the month in the first value is before June (so a month value of <6), I want the first Departure value to be automatically set to "Departure." Other rows should not be changed.

So for this example, my simplified data frame should look like this:

```
 ID Month Departure
1  A     4 Departure
2  A     4      <NA>
3  A     5      <NA>
4  A     5      <NA>
5  B    11 Departure
6  B    11      <NA>
7  B    11      <NA>
8  B    12      <NA>
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

We may create a logical condition with `duplicated` and `is.na` to assign the values in 'Departure' to the column name

```
data$Departure[with(data, !duplicated(ID) & is.na(Departure))] <-  "Departure"
```

-output

```
> data
  ID Month Departure
1  A     4 Departure
2  A     4      <NA>
3  A     5      <NA>
4  A     5      <NA>
5  B    11 Departure
6  B    11      <NA>
7  B    11      <NA>
8  B    12      <NA>
```